# Share button with ShareActionProvider added twice on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-sharing

I have an issue with a **Share Button** in the **Action Bar**.

**The screenshot:**

[image]

As you can see, there are two icons on the right. But I only added one icon (the first) which is inactive. The second one is active, and do what I want (share the content).
As a result, I'd just want the first icon with the behavior of the second one.

Where does the second icon come from ??!!

The menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/animation_detail_share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        />
</menu>
```

The fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inplace_animation_details, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.animation_detail_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.animation_detail_share);

    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

    if(mShareActionProvider != null) {

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
    }
}
```

I inflate the menu only inside the fragment, not in the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I had two issues here:

1. `createChooser()` creates the new icon
2. Had to add `setShareHistoryFileName(null);` to prevent showing another icon.

So the final code looks like:

```
...
mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sendIntent);
...
```